# Normalized json object with arrays to flatten denormalized table with specific structure

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalization, parquet

I have json object with nested objects and arrays. I want to normalize this json and convert it nito denormalized db table with pre-defined structure respecting data types like timestamp,text,int etc.
If some of field missed in json I need that in table it will be NULL. All jsons stored as parquet and then copied to redshify using copy command.

Here is an example of simplified version of such json object:

```
{
  "url": "https://zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/154571.json",
  "id": 154571,
  "external_id": null,
  "via": {
    "channel": "email",
    "source": {
      "from": {
        "address": "xxxx@waitrapp.com",
        "name": "xxxx"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "xxxx",
        "address": "support@xxxxx.com"
      },
      "rel": null
    }
  },
  "created_at": "2018-07-03T17:14:52Z",
  "collaborator_ids": ["x","a"],
  "tags": ["a","b"],
  "followup_ids": [1,2]
}
```

Here is desired structure after denormalization:

```
url,id,external_id,created_at,tags,followup_ids,via_channel,via_source_from_address,via_source_from_name
https://zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/154571.json,154571,,2018-07-03T17:14:52Z,tag-a,1,email,xxxx@waitrapp.com,xxxx
https://zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/154571.json,154571,,2018-07-03T17:14:52Z,tag-a,2,email,xxxx@waitrapp.com,xxxx
https://zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/154571.json,154571,,2018-07-03T17:14:52Z,tag-b,1,email,xxxx@waitrapp.com,xxxx
https://zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/154571.json,154571,,2018-07-03T17:14:52Z,tag-b,2,email,xxxx@waitrapp.com,xxxx
```

Here is the table:

```
create table adhoc_temp.zendesk_tickets
        (
            url text,
            id bigint,
            external_id text,
            created_at timestamp,
            tags text,
            collaborator_ids int,
            via_channel text,
            via_source_rel text,
            via_source_from_ticket_id int,
            via_source_from_subject text,
            via_source_from_address text,
            via_source_from_name text,
            via_source_to_name text,
            via_source_to_address text
        );
```

In this case fields `via_source_from_ticket_id`, `via_source_from_subject` missed in the source json, so in the table they should NULL.

I played with `json_normalize` but it doesn't respect arrays. Any way how I can join nested arrays to the main json object?